# como actualizar registro con una subconsulta MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, update, subconsultas

Como se puede realizar una actualización de varios registros, usando una subconsulta para obtener el valor que se desea ingresar en una columna.
ejemplo:

```
UPDATE tabla_1 SET valor1=(sql de subconsulta)
WHERE valor_2=1
```

Answer (score 0):

La solución la encontré en el siguiente link [solución](http://soluciones-sql.blogspot.com/2012/12/insertar-y-actualizar-desde-una.html), para realizar una actualización usando una subconsulta, use el siguiente codigo, el cual fue el que mejor me funciono.

```
UPDATE tabla_1
SET valor_1=(
    SELECT otroValor_1 
    FROM 
    (
      SELECT t2.otroValor_1,t2.id FROM tabla_2 t2
    ) as pch
    WHERE pch.id=tabla_1.fk_id
)
WHERE valor_2=1
```

en este caso dentro del *FROM* de la subconsulta, puse mi sentencia sql y asigne un alias ***pch*** para poder usar la referencia del id de la **tabla_2** en el *where* siguiente al *FROM*.

En el caso que la subconsulta fuera algo un poco mas compleja. Por ejemplo, que incluyera *joins* y se necesitara hacer una restricción con respecto a la **tabla_1**, lo hice de la siguiente forma.

```
UPDATE tabla_1
SET valor_1=(
    SELECT otroValor_1 
    FROM 
    (SELECT t.price,t1.id FROM tabla_1 t1
     JOIN tabla_2 t2 on t1.fk_id1=t2.id 
     JOIN tabla_3 t3 on t2.fk_id2=t3.id  
     JOIN tabla_4 t4 on t3.fk_id3=t4.id 
    ) as pch
    WHERE pch.id=tabla_1.id
),
valor_3=valor_4-valor_1
WHERE valor_2=1
```

Como se puede observar, en la consulta anterior, seguí la estructura de la primera solución, las únicas diferencias son el query que esta dentro del *FROM* alias, y el **valor_3**(de la tabla_1) que se esta actualizando con la operación entre el **valor_4**(de la tabla_1) y el **valor_1**(de la tabla_1) que también estamos actualizando.

*Nota: al llamar el **valor_1** para actualizar el **valor_3**, se usa la actualización de valor que estamos haciendo.*

**Adicional:**

En el post también nos explica, como se hace un insert a partir de una subconsulta. a continuacion dejo el sql de ejemplo que esta en la pagina. Aclaro que no se con exactitud si funciona, ya que no lo probé, pero lo dejo por si es de utilidad para alguien.

```
INSERT INTO resumen_sucursales (sucursal,anno,mes,ventas)
SELECT o.sucursal, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM o.fecha) AS anno, 
       EXTRACT(MONTH FROM o.fecha) AS mes,
       SUM(a.cantidad*a.precio_unitario)
FROM ordenes o INNER JOIN articulos a ON (o.id_orden=a.orden)
GROUP BY sucursal, anno, mes
```

Comment: El post es correcto. Lo unico que no me queda claro es que valor usa para actualiza valor_3 la segunda consulta. Valor_1, que valor tiene? Y no queda del todo claro que es cada tabla. Mas alla de eso, es una fiel copia del articulo que pusiste como referencia.